# IPSec - Standard ItemPrice of SoftLayer Product Package

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to order "IPsec VPN" of SoftLayer Service.

This is my order container code for it.

```
{
            'quantity': 1,
            'location': 449604, # Tokyo
            'packageId': 0,
            'prices': [
                    {'id':2048}   # IPsec Standard
            ],
    }
```

Then I got the following error.

```
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Quotes cannot be placed for the legacy additional services (package 0).
```

I cannot find such any kind of service afterwards.

Could you tell me which Product Package contains "IPsec Standard" service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the package that you are using is fine, The error is pretty clear about what is happening you are trying to place an order quote which is not allowed (even using the control portal that is not possible), for the items from the package 0 you only can call the placeOrder method and not the placeQuote method.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, Nelson. We can quote for example NetScaler VPX which is included in the package 0 because the other package is prepared for the NetScaler. Is there any way to quote IPSec service which costs $99/mo? Isn't it completely allowed to quote?

Comment: if you can do it using the control portal you can do it using the API, if you cannot do it using the control portal is likely you got the same issue using API, IPSec is service, services cannot be quoted , netScaler is a device such as a VSI or bare metal that's why you can quote it

Comment: I see. I'll check it out :)